# How to determine a plane vertical or horizontal in ARcore?

Tags: unity-game-engine, arcore

As title, I want to determine a plane is vertical or horizontal in ARcore in run-time.
How should I do this?

Comment: Check `plane.type ==  Plane.Type.HORIZONTAL_UPWARD_FACING` on frame update & proceed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [ARCore Plane.Type docs](https://developers.google.com/ar/reference/java/com/google/ar/core/Plane.Type):

```
Plane.Type t = yourPlane.getType();

if(t == Plane.Type.VERTICAL)
  // Vertical plane
else if(t == Plane.Type.Plane.Type HORIZONTAL_DOWNWARD_FACING)
  // Ceiling, camera looking up at
else if(t == Plane.Type.Plane.Type HORIZONTAL_DOWNWARD_FACING)
  // Floor, ground, camera looking down at
```